# Missed administration Page magento

Tags: php, magento, phpmyadmin

I have the following problem: I do not know the Admin URL of my site(localhost), because the most sites says to try add "admin" at the end of the URL address, But it does not work.
In the installation do Magento my wifi dropped, after it reconnected I pressed f5 and the page appears as if it had installed normally, but when the wifi dropped the installation was at 97% and at that stage the administrative part was being installed.
To visit my site I use this URL:
         http://myip/magento

To administer my site They say to use this URL:
         http://myip/magento/admin

but It does not work.
Useful information:
Site structures: Magento 2.1.3,php7.0,apache2,ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In magento 2 you can get the admin url by checking the file

```
app/etc/env.php


'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin_3h3cow',
  ),
```